# AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: wcf, rest

Have a WCF service that I am trying to add configuration for REST to.  Keep getting the AddressFilter mismatch error.  I have tried all the suggestions and gone over the addresses several times but I must be missing something in my configuration.  Was hoping someone with some more experience with REST could see what I am missing here.

My service configuration is the following:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="200" maxConcurrentInstances="200"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="www.parinc.com.PARToolkit">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IPARToolkit"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IPARToolkit" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:86/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
```

The contract is set up as:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetApps?authKey1={authKey1}&authKey2={authKey2}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string GetApps(string authKey1, string authKey2);
```

But when I try calling the service as follows (without the spaces I put in http to get the url to post here) I get the AddressFilter mismatch error:

"http://localhost:86/WebServices/PARToolkit.svc/rest/GetApps?authKey1=12345&authKey2=56789"

Answer (score 0):

if you host the service in IIS, then remove the 'rest' in your address. e.g.
h t t p://localhost:86/WebServices/PARToolkit.svc/GetApps?authKey1=12345&authKey2=56789

and also, in service configuration, no need for address in endpoint. e.g.

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IPARToolkit" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" />
```

and remove the baseAddresses sections.